# How can I set up a check box for temporary usage?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I don't have `models/message.rb` neither `send_to_all` column in messages table.
Here, I want to use `send_to_all` checkbox flag only for switching the mode to send message to all users at once.

How can I do that?

**views/messages/new.html.erb**

```
<%= f.check_box :send_to_all, :label => 'Send to all Users'  %> Check if you want to send to all users at once.
```

**messages_controller.rb**

```
    if params[:messages][:send_to_all]
        The action to send the same message to all users 

    else        
        The action to send the message to a user

    end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have a model you can't create a form associated with an object, so you have to use the `form tag helpers`.

A checkbox can be created like this:

```
check_box_tag 'send_to_all'
```

Resulting in:

```
<input id="send_to_all" name="send_to_all" type="checkbox" value="1" />
```

See more helpers [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-check_box_tag).

So, to use a form that is not associated with a model you do something like:

```
<% form_tag '/your_route' do -%>
  <div><%= check_box_tag 'send_to_all' %></div>
  <div><%= submit_tag 'Save' %></div>
<% end -%>
```

Comment: Thanks:) so should it be something like this? `<%= f.check_box_tag :send_to_all, :label => 'Send to all Users' %>`